# If word.ActiveDocument exists close it [VBA]

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

Here's my code:

```
    If Not (word.ActiveDocument Is Nothing) Then
          word.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End If
```

I get an error if there is no active document. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Maybe add ' On Error Resume Next ' before your IF statement ..

Comment: Post more of the code so we can give more specific advice.Is the document opened in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if there are open documents in the following way:

```vb
If word.Documents.Count Then '0 is falsy, all other values are truthy
      word.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
End If
```